# Error getting block from cad library file using C#

Tags: c#, autocad-plugin

[Error Warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cYYM.jpg)

I have a block cad library file, I use the following code to get the block from that library file.

```
 using (Database OpenDb = new Database(false, true))

        {

            string sPath =@"..\\MONGDON\\CadLibrary.dwg";
            OpenDb.ReadDwgFile(sPath,

                System.IO.FileShare.ReadWrite, true, "");
```

I use relative path, when I debug directly, there is no error but when I build to .dll file, it gives an error like the image above, I think it is a path error to the cad library file. Hope you can help me to fix the above error. (I put the .dll file and the library file named CadLibrary.dwg in the same folder named MONGDON).

Comment: It’s expecting the path, one level up-> MONGDON ->CadLibrary.dwg. So please make sure you have this folder structure

Comment: I tried leveling up like this: string sPath =@"..\\..\\..\\MONGDON\\CadLibrary.dwg"; but still giving the same error. Do you have a way to fix the above error?

Comment: where is your .dwg file located? Also You said that you have build as dll then how are you running the application?

Comment: I am dropping .dwg and .dll under the path: C:\Users\prote\Desktop\MONGDON\SCSMongDon.dll.  I use lisp to run the application.

Comment: I also want when I move to another computer it also automatically get the path to the dwg library file. Do you have any way?

Comment: Then you can directly give path CadLibrary.dwg, no need to give folder name if it’s in the same path. Again my question how are you running your application? As it’s dll you might be running it from some other application?

Comment: One big hint for you: you can check `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory` just above this code. It will tell you where exactly you are and use the path accordingly.

Comment: I run it from autocad application. use command "Net Load" to run the plugin!

Comment: Since the .dll file and the Acad.exe application file are located in different directories, I cannot use "Directory.GetCurrentDirectory", because this code only takes the path to the Acad.exe directory of the Autocad software, and my ".dll" file and the "dwg" library file I put in another folder.